# MFC project has linking error on Visual Studio 2013?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, mfc

When I tried to add a toolbar to my mfc project in Visual studio 2013, the following errors occurred. Has anyone worked on this? How can I fix the errors?

[mfc project in Visual studio 2013](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ezltq.png)

MFCModalOynaDlg.h

```cpp
#pragma once
    
class CMFCModalOynaDlg : public CDialogEx
{
public:
    CMFCModalOynaDlg(CWnd* pParent = NULL); 
    
    enum { IDD = IDD_MFCMODALOYNA_DIALOG }; 
    
protected:
    virtual void DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX);
    
protected:
    HICON m_hIcon;
    CToolBar m_wndToolBar;
    BOOL butD;
    
    virtual BOOL OnInitDialog();
    afx_msg void OnPaint();
    afx_msg HCURSOR OnQueryDragIcon();
    DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP()

public:
    afx_msg void OnBnClickedOk();
};
```

MFCModalOynaDlg.cpp:

```cpp
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "MFCModalOyna.h"
#include "MFCModalOynaDlg.h"
#include "afxdialogex.h"
#include "windows.h"
    
#ifdef _DEBUG
#define new DEBUG_NEW
#endif
    
CMFCModalOynaDlg::CMFCModalOynaDlg(CWnd* pParent /*=NULL*/)
    : CDialogEx(CMFCModalOynaDlg::IDD, pParent)
{
    m_hIcon = AfxGetApp()->LoadIcon(IDR_MYICON1);
}
    
void CMFCModalOynaDlg::DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX)
{
    CDialogEx::DoDataExchange(pDX);
}
    
BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CMFCModalOynaDlg, CDialogEx)
    ON_WM_PAINT()
    ON_WM_QUERYDRAGICON()
END_MESSAGE_MAP()
    
BOOL CMFCModalOynaDlg::OnInitDialog()
{
    CDialogEx::OnInitDialog();
    
    SetIcon(m_hIcon, TRUE);
    SetIcon(m_hIcon, FALSE);
    
    if (!m_wndToolBar.Create(this)|| !m_wndToolBar.LoadToolBar(IDR_TOOLBAR1)) 
    {
        TRACE0("Failed to Create Dialog Toolbar\n");
        EndDialog(IDCANCEL);
    }
    butD = TRUE;
    CRect rcClientOld;
    CRect rcClientNew; 
    
    GetClientRect(rcClientOld);
    RepositionBars(AFX_IDW_CONTROLBAR_FIRST, AFX_IDW_CONTROLBAR_LAST, 0, reposQuery, rcClientNew);
  
    CPoint ptOffset(rcClientNew.left - rcClientOld.left, rcClientNew.top - rcClientOld.top);
    
    CRect rcChild;
    CWnd* pwndChild = GetWindow(GW_CHILD); 
    
    while (pwndChild) 
    {
        pwndChild->GetWindowRect(rcChild); 
        ScreenToClient(rcChild);
    
        rcChild.OffsetRect(ptOffset);
        pwndChild->MoveWindow(rcChild, FALSE); 
        pwndChild = pwndChild->GetNextWindow();
    }
    
    CRect rcWindow;
    GetWindowRect(rcWindow);

    rcWindow.right += rcClientOld.Width() - rcClientNew.Width();

    rcWindow.bottom += rcClientOld.Height() - rcClientNew.Height();
    MoveWindow(rcWindow, FALSE);
    
    RepositionBars(AFX_IDW_CONTROLBAR_FIRST, AFX_IDW_CONTROLBAR_LAST, 0);
    
    return TRUE;
}
```

> Error 1   error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "protected: void
> __thiscall CMFCModalOynaDlg::OnPaint(void)" (?OnPaint@CMFCModalOynaDlg@@IAEXXZ)
>
> Error 2   error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "protected: struct HICON__ * __thiscall CMFCModalOynaDlg::OnQueryDragIcon(void)" (?OnQueryDragIcon@CMFCModalOynaDlg@@IAEPAUHICON__@@XZ)
>
> Error 3   error LNK1120: 2 unresolved externals   D:\VSprogram\MFCModalOyna\Debug\MFCModalOyna.exe

[When I tried to add a toolbar to my mfc project in Visual studio 2013, the following errors occurred.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qk2Ca.png)

Comment: Your header declares an `OnPaint` member function for `CMFCModalOynaDlg` that you never provide a definition for. That's why you get a linker error.

Comment: That file looks wrong. It has the function `BOOL CMFCModalOynaDlg::OnInitDialog()` and then just code not in any function.

Comment: @AndrewTruckle looks like just bad indentation